# Write and read an integer in a char *

Tags: c

I'm coding a little server in c (a chat server) and i want to write and read an integer (and other type of variable like short int, unsigned int blablabla) in my char *data.

I have a structure DataOutput :

```
typedef struct t_dataoutput
{
  char *data;
  unsigned int pos;
} DataOutput;
```

And i have a function to write an int :

```
int writeInt(DataOutput *out, int i)
{
  // here i resize my char *data
  out->data[out->pos] = (i >> 24);
  out->data[out->pos + 1] = (i >> 16) & 0xff;
  out->data[out->pos + 2] = (i >> 8) & 0xff;
  out->data[out->pos + 3] = i & 0xff;
  out->pos += 4;
}
```

In my main function i want to try my code :

```
int main()
{
  DataOutput out;

  out.writeInt(&out, 9000);
  printf("%d\n", (out.data[0] << 24) | (out.data[1] << 16) | (out.data[2] << 8) | (out.data[3]));
}
```

But the result is not good ... Why ? I don't understand :(

Sorry for my english i'm french ^^ !

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataOutput.data should be forced to unsigned char because char are sometimes signed, depending of the compiler, and shifting signed chars or casting them to int (even implicitly) will propagate the sign bit:

```
typedef struct t_dataoutput
{
  unsigned char *data;
  unsigned int pos;
} DataOutput;
```

The memory for out->data has to be allocated before filled.
You can use realloc in the writeInt function like that:

```
int writeInt(DataOutput *out, int i)
{
  // here i resize my char *data
  out->data = realloc(out->data, out->pos + 4);
  // TODO: test if out->data == NULL --> not enough memory!
  out->data[out->pos] = (i >> 24) & 0xff;
  out->data[out->pos + 1] = (i >> 16) & 0xff;
  out->data[out->pos + 2] = (i >> 8) & 0xff;
  out->data[out->pos + 3] = i & 0xff;
  out->pos += 4;
}
```

Comment: Ok i understand but with this solution i can't write a negativ integer ? I think i will be useless but it's just a question.

And an other question, with realloc you have to add the current buffer size with out->pos ? Or juste realloc(out->data, sizeof(int)) is good ?
And i think i have to add 1byte to get the correct size if i had to add the current size in realloc

Comment: _will propagate the sign bit_ Even more complex. According to the standard, right shift of a negative integer is implementation defined behavior, and left shift of a negative integer is undefined behavior.

Comment: You can write negative integers without problems; in every case it is when decoding that you'll have to know what the data is representing so you can cast it correctly. `realloc(out->data, sizeof(int))` will reduce your data to 4 bytes, erasing the rest, so in my opinion it is not good especially when pos != 0. You don't have to add one more byte: you're writting 4 bytes so you just need four more bytes of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I initialize my structure with this function :

```
void initDataOutput(DataOutput *out)
{
  out->data = NULL;
  out->pos = 0;
}
```

But i can't do that :

```
DataOutput out;
char tmp[4];
out.data = tmp;
out.pos = 0;
```

Because in my code i could write things like that for example :

```
DataOutput out;
writeInt(&out, 1);
writeString(&out, "Hello");
sendData(&out);
```

where the int is a kind of packet id and "Hello" is the connexion message, but if it's an other id it's not the same information in out->data

Oh sorry and I don't understand what you mean when you say : avoid shifting signed integers and chars

I must use an unsigned char *data in my DataOutput structure ?

Comment: If you comment an answer, please use "_add a comment_" instead of making another answer. (Yes, it is a bit hard if you have some code to add. In that case, consider editing the original question). Second, why do you set `data` to `NULL`? Do you allocate the buffer somewhere? Regarding shifts: strictly speaking, you should use `unsigned int` and `unsigned char` if you do shifting. In practice, using `int/char` _to store data_, and casting them to `unsigned` before shifting, may work.

Comment: I initialize data to NULL because it's a pointer :)
I allocate my buffer just after write data

Comment: Yep, I meant why don't you allocate memory for `data`? Or is it done somewhere else?

Comment: It's done juste before write my data :) but i don't write it in the post because i thin it's useless to understand. It's just a call to realloc